gitleaks to report only the secrets on the current branch in gitlab cicd
I am trying to integrate gitleaks in gitlab cicd pipeline. I am using the following code and it works.
In the parameter, I am passing the branch as a committed branch. However that branch is created from the master branch so, gitleak searches the commit history of the master branch and it provides history of secrets written and removed on the master branch as well which I don't want.
I am expecting only the secrets written on the current branch which should be reported.
How could this be achieved?
Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.
stages:
  - test

secret_scan:
  stage: test
  image: 
    name: "zricethezav/gitleaks"
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - gitleaks detect --source . --verbose branch=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --report-format json --report-path gitleaks-report.json || true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - gitleaks-report.json


According to the gitleaks README the detect command uses the output of git log -p for the analysis. You can set the --log-opts flag to restrict git log -p to only changes between the master branch and your commit branch. Something like this might work for you:
gitleaks detect --source . --log-opts="master..${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" --verbose branch=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH --report-format json --report-path gitleaks-report.json || true

You can test this by running git log -p and git log -p master..<BRANCH_NAME> locally when you have <BRANCH_NAME> checked out
